# Excel macro, search by row return next cell's value

Tags: excel, macros

I have this Macro already working:

```
    Sub ListSheetsValuesAreOn()
  Dim X As Long, Data As Variant, Uniques As String, SH As Worksheet, NewSH As Worksheet
  With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each SH In Worksheets
      Data = Application.Transpose(SH.Range("C23", SH.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)))
      For X = 1 To UBound(Data)
        If IsEmpty(.Item(Data(X))) Then
          .Item(Data(X)) = Data(X) & "|" & SH.Name
        ElseIf Data(X) = Split(.Item(Data(X)), "|")(0) And _
               Not .Item(Data(X)) Like "*|*" & SH.Name & "*" Then
          .Item(Data(X)) = .Item(Data(X)) & ", " & SH.Name
        End If
      Next
    Next
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set NewSH = ActiveSheet
    NewSH.Range("A1").Resize(.Count) = Application.Transpose(.Items)
  End With
  NewSH.Name = "Result Sheet"
  NewSH.Columns("A").TextToColumns , xlDelimited, , , 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, "|"
  NewSH.Columns("A:B").AutoFit
End Sub
```

What this script does is:
  Read values in C column and search all the workbook to find these values. 
  Returning the values and the sheets where they've been found.
But I want to return not each value in C but the next one in column D.
Example:

```
Sheets 1...n                                   Expected output (new sheet)

  C     |    D                                   A        |       B

  item 1|description of item 1       description of item 1|1,4,6

  item 2|description of item 2       description of item 2|3,7,11,12

   ...  | ....                           ....             |   .....

  item m|description of item m       description of item m| 5,9,15,24
```

Comment: Data should included column D then, then Data will be 2-D array, step through and you can fix.

Comment: any code for this solution? I am quite novice in excel macros

Comment: Have you tried changing the `C`s to `D`s in the `Data = ...` line?

Comment: Replacing C with D is not working...

Comment: Few questions `If isEmpty(.Item(Data(X))) then .Item(Data(X)) = Data(X) & "|" & SH.Name` that's just the sheet name, what is an example of expected data? Where do you want to place the data from column D and when?

Comment: column C: item name, D: Description. Expected data: Column A:Description of each item , column B:Worksheets where each item found

Comment: I'm a little time limited but I'll post an answer just now, it wont be a mark up of your code but should show you how to do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one:

```
Sub Answer()

   Dim dict As Object
   Dim Data As Variant
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim rng As Range



   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   With dict
      For Each SH In Worksheets
         Data = Application.Transpose(SH.Range("C23", SH.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)))
         For X = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)

            If IsEmpty(.Item(Data(1, X))) Then
               .Item(Data(1, X)) = Data(2, X) + "|" + SH.Name
               '.Item(Data(2, X)) = .Item(Data(1, X))
            ElseIf Split((dict.Item(Data(1, X))), "|")(0) = Split((Data(2, X)), "|")(0) Then
               .Item(Data(1, X)) = .Item(Data(1, X)) + ", " + SH.Name
            End If
         Next X
    Next
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set NewSH = ActiveSheet
    NewSH.Range("A1").Resize(.Count) = Application.Transpose(.Items)

  End With
  NewSH.Name = "Result Sheet"
  NewSH.Columns("A").TextToColumns , xlDelimited, , , 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, "|"
  NewSH.Columns("A:B").AutoFit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Few caveats of below solution, I'm using columns A and B as sources, my data is not in need of transposition.

```
Sub Answer()

   Dim dict As Object
   Dim Data As Variant
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim rng As Range



   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   With dict
      For Each SH In Worksheets
         Data = Application.Transpose(SH.Range("A1", SH.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)))
         For X = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)

            If IsEmpty(.Item(Data(X, 1))) Then
               .Item(Data(X, 1)) = Data(X, 2) & "|" & SH.Name
            ElseIf Data(X, 1) = Split(.Item(Data(X, 1)), "|")(0) And _
                  Not .Item(Data(X, 2)) Like "*|*" & SH.Name & "*" Then
               .Item(Data(X, 1)) = .Item(Data(X, 2)) & ", " & SH.Name
            End If
         Next X
      Next ' For Each
      ...
   End With
   ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Used your answer with some modifications (A1 -> C23 and B -> D ) because my source is from C23.... and from D23.....

Comment: What issues are you seeing?